# Migrate felix annotation property final String into OSGI

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

Can someone write correct this migration to OSGI?

```
@Component(immediate = true, service = CustomExternalizer.class,
            properties = {
            "process.label=Custom Externalizer Service"
            },
            configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
    @Designate(ocd = CustomExternalizerImpl.Config.class)
    public class CustomExternalizerImpl implements CustomExternalizer {


// its felix => this need to OSGI
    @Property(label = "Domains", unbounded = PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY,
            description = "List of domain mappings. In the form: '<site root path> scheme://domain[:port]'."
                    + "Standard required names are 'author' and  'publish'")
    public static final String PROPERTY_EXTERNALIZER_DOMAINS = "externalizer.domains";

@ObjectClassDefinition
    protected @interface Config {

        @AttributeDefinition(
                ???????????
    }
```

I try some approach, but have only mix

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to migrate this code to use OSGi R 6 annotations instead of Felix SCR? The snippet you posted appears to contain a mix of both.

Comment: Remove all the Felix SCR imports, and use this guide https://blog.osoco.de/2016/05/migrating-from-the-apache-felix-scr-annotations-to-the-osgi-declarative-services-annotations/

Comment: thk, I resolve it self, yet